# Actions must be plain objects. Use customer middleware for async actions in React Native

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I'm trying to use AsyncStorage in my react-native app. In the restore session function, I get the user name and location, using AsyncStorage.multiGet. But I get the "Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async asctions" error.

my index.js looks like this:

```
const loggerMiddleware = createLogger();
const store = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware, loggerMiddleware));

const nsidenotify = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
);
```

My Action looks like:

```
export function sessionRestoring(){
  return {
    type: types.SESSION_RESTORING,
  };
};

export function signinRequest() {
  return {
    type: types.SIGNIN_REQUEST,
  };
}

export async function restoreSession() {
  console.log('Restoring Session');
  let userName = '';
  let userLocation = '';
  await  AsyncStorage.multiGet(['userName', 'userLocation'])
  .then(response => {
    userName = response['userName'];
    userLocation = response['userLocation'];
    console.log(`Found ${userName} from ${userLocation}`);
  })
  if (typeof userName == 'string'){
    return (dispatch) => {
      console.log('Dispatch Session Restoring');
      dispatch(sessionRestoring());
        return FIREBASE_AUTH.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
          if (user) {
            user.name = userName;
            user.location = userLocation;
            dispatch(signinRequestSuccess(user));
          }
        })
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Redux actions cannot do asynchronous operations.
Use a library like redux sagas to do these operations.
Read up on Redux sagas and side effects of redux and why it can't be used for asynchronous actions.